# Array implementation of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree

I'm trying to convert a list-based tree implementation into an array-based implementation with the parent at the ith index, left child at 2ith index and right child at 2i+1th index. for some reason the conversion results in loss of data for trees with bigger number of nodes.  I'd like to know what all boundary conditions i need to check for while implementing this. Thanks!

Comment: `list` and `array` suggest you already have a language in mind. Perhaps you can tag your question with that language?

Comment: Well, it is simple math if all nodes have the same number of children: root @ 0, L @ 1, R @ 2, LL@3,LR@4,RL@5,RR@6 - so you can see that the pattern - left child is at 2*i + 1, right child at 2*i + 2. If your methods are implemented properly, there is no issue. regarding boundary conditions: you can have at max N generations where sum(2**0...N) <= arrayLength.

Comment: Only with a "bigger number of nodes"? How big? You're not suffering from some integer overflow, are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your language uses zero-based indices the children of node `i` go into `2i + 1` and `2i + 2` not `2i` and `2i + 1`. The later works for one-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the head at 0 or 1?  Choosing '0' will definitely cause problems, unless you adjust your formula.